# How to numerically compute value of a function given as a infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

I have function $f(t)$ defined as follow:
$$
f(t) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}
\frac{(-b)^n(-a)^k\binom{n+k}{k}}
{\Gamma(k(\alpha-\beta)+(n+1)\alpha-\gamma)}
t^{k(\alpha-\beta)+n\alpha}
$$
where $a,b,\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ -- some real constants such that $\alpha\geq\beta$, $\alpha>\gamma$.

I'd like to compute values of this function numerically to draw its graph. In my case constants $a$ and $b$ are big ($a,b\approx 10^8$), $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ are small ($\alpha = 2$, $0<\beta<1$, $\gamma = -1$).

At first approach I tried to cut infinite sum at some level, however sequence $a_{kn}$ for given $t$
$$
a_{kn} =\frac{(-b)^n(-a)^k\binom{n+k}{k}}
{\Gamma(k(\alpha-\beta)+(n+1)\alpha-\gamma)}
t^{k(\alpha-\beta)+n\alpha}
$$
converges to zero very slow and I have to take too many terms in sums to obtain result in reasonable time.

My question:
How to compute such sums numerically with good accuracy and in reasonable time? (I have experience in using softwere for symbolic computation, but for example in Mathematica for $a$ and $b$ in given level command NSum does not work for such big $a,b$)

Comment: There is a whole class of techniques known as "series acceleration" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration
You might have luck with Aitken's delta-squared process.

Comment: I think you are leaving the realm where Mathematica will be useful. My guess is that you'll need higher precision arithmetic, extreme care to make sure not to overflow individual contributions to the $a_{nk}$, and depending on the rate of decay, perhaps parallelization. These can all be achieved in C++, but it is significantly more effort than using Maple/Matlab/Mathematica.